# Writing to a character array that is a member of a struct

Tags: c, arrays, struct, segmentation-fault, fgets

this is my first time posting a question here - I've searched for ones that are similar, but none came up that I found.

Here is the snippet from my header:

```
#define LINE_LEN_MAX 256

typedef struct line_description {
    char buffer[LINE_LEN_MAX + 1];
    [...]
} line;
```

And here is the snippet from my main function:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    line *lineRead;

    //input: valid FILE *, read from cmdline
    //char buffer[LINE_LEN_MAX + 1];

    while(fgets(lineRead->buffer, LINE_LEN_MAX + 1, input) != NULL) {

        [...]

        memset(lineRead->buffer, 0, LINE_LEN_MAX + 1);
    }
}
```

I keep getting a segfault. If I comment out the 'memset()' line I can read exactly 3 lines from my input file before getting a segfault.

However, if I replace 'lineRead->buffer' with a local char[] I am able to read my input file perfectly.

What am I not understanding about structs here? What I think I want is a pointer to the beginning of the char[] inside the struct, but obviously this is not what is happening.

EDIT: Sorry, forgot to specify: I am not using dynamic memory here.

Comment: Memory allocation problem. lineRead have never been allocated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lineRead` in your program is an uninitialized pointer, which is probably not what you wanted.

You should allocate some storage space for a line by writing e.g. `line lineRead` instead, which will allocate a `line` struct on the stack.  Then use `.` rather than `->` to access its members.

Comment: +1 , wow, someone actually read that the OP is not using dynamic allocation and just provided an answer without harping on malloc() :)

Answer (score 1):

You declare `lineRead` to be a pointer to a `line`, but you don't actually set it to point to anything. When you then try to access the random location that the uninitialized pointer happens to point to, you get a segmentation fault.

If you only need `lineRead` in the local scope it shouldn't be a pointer, just declare it as

```
line lineRead;
```

If `lineRead` needs to live longer that the function and so really needs to be dynamically allocated, use a pointer but also reserve memory for the struct it should be pointing to:

```
line *lineRead = malloc(sizeof(line));
lineRead->buffer[0] = '\0'; // or any other initializations...
```

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly the problem. I only needed lineRead on the stack.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you just left something out of your snippet, but you didn't show the structure being allocated.

```
line *lineRead; // uninitialized pointer: access to any field crashes
lineRead = (line*) malloc( sizeof( line_description ) );
```

Or, if you don't need it to be on the heap (especially considering that a stack object in outermost scope in `main` has lifetime of the entire program anyway),

```
line lineRead; // don't need to use a pointer!
```

Comment: Yes, thank you very much - I'm not using dynamic memory here.